# SWIFT: NSURL Always either Nil or unusable

Tags: macos, swift, nsurl

So in my Swift App, I have a function that selects a folder/Drive - then I want to use the NSURL as a String. However- when I print the NSURL it comes up as "Optional(file:///(stuff goes here)" BUT When I make it a String it comes up as Nil. Is there something I'm doing wrong? 
Code below

```
@IBAction func selectDrive(sender: AnyObject) {
    var openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
    openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    openPanel.canChooseDirectories = true
    openPanel.canCreateDirectories = true
    openPanel.canChooseFiles = false
    openPanel.beginWithCompletionHandler { (result) -> Void in
        if result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton {
            println(openPanel.URL)
            self.url = openPanel.URL!

            var loc = String(contentsOfURL: self.url)
            println("Location is at \(loc)")
            // var str = String(system("diskutil info \(loc) | grep UUID:"))

        }

    }
}
```

I also have the following declared at the top

```
var url = NSURL()
@IBOutlet weak var driveLabel: NSTextField!
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I spent a couple of hours last night trying to either get the console output to come back as a String, trying to convert the NSURL to a String, trying to delete the entire app...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSOpenPanel` returns always an url with the `file://` scheme, you can get the string representation with its `path` property

```
@IBAction func selectDrive(sender: AnyObject) {
    var openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
    openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    openPanel.canChooseDirectories = true
    openPanel.canCreateDirectories = true
    openPanel.canChooseFiles = false
    openPanel.beginWithCompletionHandler { (result) -> Void in
        if result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton {

            self.url = openPanel.URL!
            println("Location is at \(self.url.path!)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! That worked like a charm. Might I ask where you found that? I was looking for a Java API Styled page that listed methods/variables but all I found was Stackoverflow questions with the .URL or .URLs Also I don't think I've ever had to type self so many times before. Actually. I don't think I've ever had to explicitly say self

Comment: actually the first place to look is the documentation. In Xcode option-click on a symbol to get a popover with its declaration. Clicking on any link in the popover opens a new window with the complete documentation. Usually you need `self` in closures like the completion handler. The compiler will tell you where it's needed.